# Is the bias of the accelerometer MPU9250/6000 significantly high?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, i2c, accelerometer

The bias for Accelerometer of X and Y are very different from 0 when the sensor is flat. The AccZ axis is as expected. I can correct for this bias in code, however I wanted to know if this level of bias is typical of MPU range, if not I may consider getting another one. Sensor: MPU9250. The values should be multiplied by 10, so 0.92 on Z axis is 9.2m/s^2 (acceleration). -0.39 is 3.9m/s^2.

https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf
(datasheet)
https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/RM-MPU-9250A-00-v1.6.pdf
(register map)

[image]

Comment: You do not say what your units are (-0.39 **what**?), you do not say which is the z-axis, you do not say what accelerometer you are using, you do not say how the measured accelerometer bias compares with the datasheet values, you do not say *how* level.  Could you please *edit your question* so that it has enough information to at least begin to answer your question.

Comment: OK -- I see it's an MPU9250 (who reads titles?).  A link to a datasheet would be helpful, and the rest of my questions still stand.

Comment: Can you place your sensor in the 6 cardinal orientations and report the results? That should be a good way to see whether it's a static bias in each axis, or if something else is going on.

Comment: @TimWescott I have made edits as asked thank you :)

Comment: From my experience the bias should only be a few LSB at most. Your bias looks huge. Can you show your code? Could you have made an error in "endianness" of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is critical datasheet stuff, so you can expect to find it there -- to the point where, if it's *not* in the datasheet, I would genenerally just not buy the part.

Normally the datasheet parameter you'd look for would be "bias".  This one chooses to call it "Zero-G Initial Calibration Tolerance", and it's \$\pm 60 \mathrm{mg}\$ for the X and Y axes, and \$\pm 80 \mathrm{mg}\$.

**You're way over that**, so you have some other problem.

Note that the specifications are for the chip at 25C -- they also give a "Zero-G Level Change vs. Temperature" at \$\pm 1.5 \mathrm{mg / ^\circ C}\$.  This is no surprise, accelerometers are always drifty with temperature, and little silicon MEMS accelerometers are the worst of the lot.  So if you're going to use this thing, you can predict how much worse you can expect it to be at the temperature extremes than at room temperature.